# Restrict a User to show only their record in employee view

Tags: xml, security, odoo

Hello i want to restrict users to show and update only their data but not other employees.
I have tried access rule but not working. Please help me out on this.

My code

```
       <field name="name">No Edit</field>

        <field name="model_id" ref="hr.model_hr_employee"/>
       <field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
       <field name="domain_force"> [('user_id','!=',user.id)] </field>
```

And new group is required to be created then please guide me with that too.
I checked out this below link answer but didn't work out.

[Record Rule to allow a User to update their own Employee record without belonging to Officer group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417029/record-rule-to-allow-a-user-to-update-their-own-employee-record-without-belongin)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="employee_access_user">
    <field name="name">Employee Access Rules</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_employee"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="0"/>
</record>
```